# CsQuery: how to iterate over all elements?

Tags: c#, csquery

I need to implement a function that returns the first element the has Id attribute that contains a certain string.

in HAP I used to implement it as follows:

```
    protected HtmlNode GetElementByIdPattern(string pattern)
    {
        return doc
            .DocumentNode
            .Descendants()
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attributes["id"] != null && e.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains(pattern));
    }
```

How do I loop over all elements in CsQuery?

Comment: You're using an operator that specifically grabs a single result.  There is only one result.  If you want *all* of the results, then don't use an operator that just grabs a single result...

Comment: which operator are you talking about? this is HAP don't mind it. I need the equivalent of .Descendants()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
    protected static CQ GetElementByIdPattern(CQ doc, string contains)
    {
        string select = string.Format("*[id*={0}]", contains);
        return doc.Select(select).First();
    }
```

Based on the jQuery syntax: $('*[id*=contains]: first')

Answer (score 0):

```
 function CQ test(string contains, string selector)
 {
    CsQuery.CQ page="<div id="test first"></div>";
    return page[selector+"[id*="+contains+"]:first"];
 }
```

It's will return a CQ object you can manipulate with it as you want.

Comment: my problem is i want it to be agnostic to the selector. which means any selector that has id*="+contains+"

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by your last comment.